# Unable to install Subversion on Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, svn, yum

I am attempting to install the subversion client on Centos 6.7 but after running:

`yum install subversion`

I get the below response:

```
Error: Package: subversion-1.6.17-1.el5.x86_64 (amberdms-updates)
       Requires: libneon.so.25()(64bit)
Error: Package: subversion-1.6.17-1.el5.x86_64 (amberdms-updates)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python26-2.6.5-6.el5.x86_64 (amberdms-os)
           python(abi) = 2.6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Do I need to manually install the above dependencies?

Or is there another way of installing subversion?

Comment: If subversion is contained in the standard centos 6 repositories, then I guess libneon etc. should also be in there. Did you mess with the repos? Please show your repository definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running CentOS 6, but you've installed third party repositories `amberdms-updates` and `amberdms-os`, possibly among others, which are designed for CentOS 5.

Remove them (and any other inappropriate repos) and replace them with the correct repositories.

After doing so, you will need to clean old metadata from your system and replace existing inappropriate packages with correct packages.

```
yum clean all
yum distro-sync
```

Comment: Thanks. My boss setup this server (***face palm***). How would I go about uninstalling `amberdms-updates` and `amberdms-os`? `yum remove amberdms-os`?

Comment: Probably by removing the repo files. But I've never heard of those repos before. I'd suggest searching for them to see what they are.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I simply had to update the amberdms repos to Centos 6 - [Amberdms CentOS 6 repositories](https://repos.jethrocarr.com/config/centos/6/amberdms-c6-public.repo). Then I ran `yum clean all` - `yum distro-sync` - `yum install subversion`

Comment: @NicholasLaw That works too. But remember to `yum clean all` and `yum distro-sync` before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you are using a wrong repository. This can be inferred from your package name: subversion-1.6.17-1.**el5**, so this clearly is a CentOS5 packages.

Remove (or disable) the `amberdms` repositories, do a `yum clean all` and finally a `yum install subversion`